# How to transpose a table in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, transpose

I have the following table:

| ID | VAR1 | VAR2 | VAR3 | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 01JAN2010 | 01JAN2011 |
| ABC1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 01JAN2011 | 01JAN2012 |
| ABC2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 01JAN2010 | 01JAN2011 |
| ABC2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 01JAN2011 | 01JAN2012 |
| ABC2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 01JAN2012 | 01JAN2013 |

and I want to transpose it like this:

| ID | VAR | VALUE | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 | VAR1 | 0 | 01JAN2010 | 01JAN2011 |
| ABC1 | VAR2 | 0 | 01JAN2010 | 01JAN2011 |
| ABC1 | VAR3 | 1 | 01JAN2010 | 01JAN2011 |
| ABC1 | VAR1 | 1 | 01JAN2011 | 01JAN2012 |
| ABC1 | VAR2 | 0 | 01JAN2011 | 01JAN2012 |
| ABC1 | VAR3 | 1 | 01JAN2011 | 01JAN2012 |
| ABC2 | VAR1 | 0 | 01JAN2010 | 01JAN2011 |
| ABC2 | VAR2 | 0 | 01JAN2010 | 01JAN2011 |
| ABC2 | VAR3 | 1 | 01JAN2010 | 01JAN2011 |
| ABC2 | VAR1 | 1 | 01JAN2011 | 01JAN2012 |
| ABC2 | VAR2 | 0 | 01JAN2011 | 01JAN2012 |
| ABC2 | VAR3 | 0 | 01JAN2011 | 01JAN2012 |
| ABC2 | VAR1 | 0 | 01JAN2012 | 01JAN2013 |
| ABC2 | VAR2 | 0 | 01JAN2012 | 01JAN2013 |
| ABC2 | VAR3 | 0 | 01JAN2012 | 01JAN2013 |

Here is a reproducible example of the first table:

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter=",";
input ID :$8. VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VALID_FROM:date9. VALID_TO:date9.;
format VALID: date9.;
datalines;
ABC1,0,0,1,01JAN2010,01JAN2011
ABC1,1,0,1,01JAN2011,01JAN2012
ABC2,0,0,1,01JAN2010,01JAN2011
ABC2,1,0,0,01JAN2011,01JAN2012
ABC2,0,0,0,01JAN2012,01JAN2013
;
run;
```

Being new to SAS I don't really know how to proceed? Arrays? proc transpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use PROC TRANSPOSE but it can also be done with a data step.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want(rename=(col1=value)) name=var;
   by id valid_:;
   var var:;
   run;
```

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know why when running this transpose to a bigger dataset I get more columns that expected ? I end up with COL2,...,COL4.

Comment: The BY variables in your example are unique.  Try showing data that is representative of the actual data.